# How is foreign keys stored when not having an ID-column?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I'm wondering if you could theoretically drop the ID-column when splitting up tables in MySQL.

Lets say I have a table with this information:

```
+-----------+-----------+  +-----------+---------+
|   Name    | CountryID |  | CountryID | Country |
+-----------+-----------+  +-----------+---------+
| Theressa  |         1 |  |         1 | America |
| Chiquita  |         1 |  +-----------+---------+
| Harlan    |         1 |
| Vanda     |         1 |
| Dudley    |         1 |
| Catherine |         1 |
| Tad       |         1 |
| Darcey    |         1 |
| Antonette |         1 |
| Renetta   |         1 |
| Arla      |         1 |
| Emery     |         1 |
| Alla      |         1 |
| Antonetta |         1 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

```
+-----------+---------+  +---------+
|   Name    | Country |  | Country |
+-----------+---------+  +---------+
| Theressa  | America |  | America |
| Chiquita  | America |  +---------+
| Harlan    | America |
| Vanda     | America |
| Dudley    | America |
| Catherine | America |
| Tad       | America |
| Darcey    | America |
| Antonette | America |
| Renetta   | America |
| Arla      | America |
| Emery     | America |
| Alla      | America |
| Antonetta | America |
+-----------+---------+
```

Could the table below take less space than the above? Would the foreign key "understand" that the "America" in the Person-table be linked to the one Country-table, taking less space than the ID-version, as it already references to the other table.

I'm confusing myself, so I hope some of you understand what my question is.

Comment: You shouldn't worry yourself about the space. The foreign key doesn't "understand" anything. What foreign keys do is enforce integrity (primary purpose, they do more). That means you can't insert random data in a table if it doesn't exist in another table, if they're referenced via FK. Now, as for images - what you've done with 1st image is correct. What you've done with the second one is a crime and you should be imprisoned and forbidden to develop, ever. When it comes to space, databases use various mechanisms to optimize space used, it should never be your worry.

Comment: This is an incarnation of the age-old natural vs surrogate key debate, which isn't as clear-cut as @N.B. would have you believe.  There is no crime of using natural keys: indeed, in *some* situations, it can be a very wise move indeed - however, such situations are the exception rather than the norm and so I would recommend that any newcomer to database design avoid them until they appreciate the potential pitfalls.

Comment: As for storage, see [Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html): a `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8` column will require 8 bytes of storage for each record that contains the string `'America'`; whereas a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` column will require only 1 byte of storage for each record.  Thus your latter example will consume ~8 times more storage than your former example; joining the tables on the `Country` column will accordingly be slower as longer comparisons are required, but often fewer joins are necessary in such a situation.

Comment: @eggyal the natural vs surrogate key argument is indeed a dark deep deep swamp of misfortune and lots of overtime. Regardless they are both powerful concepts when applied correctly.

Comment: However, the storage and performance concerns explained in my previous comment are negligible in most situations and should rarely influence one's schema design decisions.  Remember Knuth's maxim: "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*".

Comment: Thanks for the input. As @N.B. said, I know that's not good if what I'm asking is not working. However, it's nice to see that this may be an old debate so that I'm not the only one wondering about the best way of doing things like this. I know you shouldn't really care about space when it's this small, this is just a question of concepts. Again, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an inteligent database who replaces the String "America" by an arbitrary pointer. This solution will need to having a column with an numeric ID and it will be the same

Use the int ID. It will save space even if it is not a real issue. It will make index to work faster and save you a lot of problems. Lets say that someone writes "America" vs "AMERICA".  Strings are more complex that they seem. Countries have different names in different languages. Do the country have especial character.  "España" vs "Spain".

P.S. If you want a legible primary key use the ISO codes. Example "US".